# Spring and Spring security configuration help, cannot find a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

I keep receiving the exception with a message: "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined" even though the bean is defined as a service in the UserDetailsServiceImpl class. Such as:

```
@Service(value="userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
```

I am using the latest Spring and Spring Security.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am pasting the configuration of my spring xml files. The spring-security.xml shows that it can find beans from the servlet-context.xml when using the component-scan.

Thank you

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<beans:import resource="classpath*:servlet-context.xml"/> 

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"></global-method-security>    

<http auto-config="true" >
    <!-- Filtering url patterns -->

    <!-- Anonymous users -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <!-- Login and logout controls -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/profile"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

</http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="authenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

                                              <!-- Data source configuration -->

<!-- JDBC configuration for ORM -->
<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName"/>
   <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
   <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
</beans:bean>   

<!-- Hibernate session Factory -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />

   <!-- All the model packages with hibernate annotations that need to be scanned. -->
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
       <beans:value>
           com.package.registration.models
       </beans:value>
   </beans:property>

   <!-- Hibernate specific properties -->
   <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
       <beans:props>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
           <beans:prop key="org.hibernate.transaction">true</beans:prop>
       </beans:props>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- A transaction manager for working with Hibernate SessionFactories -->
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.app" />
```

Comment: Might want to format that exception so we don't have to scroll to the right quite so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put a component scan in your other Spring config file, not just the servlet config.

They're different contexts, one loaded by the context loader listener, one by the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that servlet-context.xml is DispatcherServlet specific. So I removed all the configuration from there and inserted in a new spring.xml file. I added that to the contextConfigLocation in the web.xml. It works now!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="<your package name" />
```

To you application context, otherwise Spring won't know where to look for beans declared with annotations.  Note, Spring will scan the package you specify and all subpackages.